# big int giving me wrong results in equality

Tags: go, bigint

For some reason I'm getting the wrong result from big int when I test the equality even though the mod result is actually correct!
For example, I would like to calculate 2015%2 which results in 1.

When I use big int, I get false when I do this:

```
fmt.Println((test.Mod(big.NewInt(2015),big.NewInt(2)))==big.NewInt(1))
```

However, when I use regular int, I get true (which is the correct thing anyway):

```
fmt.Println(2015%2==1)
```

Am I supposed to do the equality differently when using big int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Package big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/)
>
> ```
> import "math/big"
> ```
>
> [func NewInt](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt)
>
> ```
> func NewInt(x int64) *Int
> ```
>
> NewInt allocates and returns a new Int set to x.
>
> [func (*Int) Cmp](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Cmp)
>
> ```
> func (x *Int) Cmp(y *Int) (r int)
> ```
>
> Cmp compares x and y and returns:
>
> ```
> -1 if x <  y
>  0 if x == y
> +1 if x >  y
> ```

The variables `a` and `b` are pointers: `*big.Int`. Use the `Cmp` method to compare values. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    a := big.NewInt(42)
    fmt.Printf("a: %[1]T %[1]p %[1]v\n", a)
    b := big.NewInt(42)
    fmt.Printf("b: %[1]T %[1]p %[1]v\n", b)
    fmt.Println("pointers:", a == b)        // compare pointers
    fmt.Println("values:  ", a.Cmp(b) == 0) // compare values

    fmt.Println()
    test := new(big.Int)
    fmt.Println((test.Mod(big.NewInt(2015), big.NewInt(2))).Cmp(big.NewInt(1)) == 0)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TH6UzceZ4y

Output:

```
a: *big.Int 0x1040a0c0 42
b: *big.Int 0x1040a0d0 42
pointers: false
values:   true

true
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the (*int)Cmp function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    a := big.NewInt(5)
    b := big.NewInt(5)
    fmt.Println(a == b)
    fmt.Println(a.Cmp(b))
}
```